# Can not download Angular.js

Tags: angularjs, download

[image]

Hi, I am having difficulties to download Angular.js from their website. This(first picture) is what it does after I click the download button. Any idea how to download it any other way? Thank YOu[image]

Comment: https://code.angularjs.org/1.7.9/angular-1.7.9.zip if you want 1.7.9 version then download and unzip it. Alternately you can use cdn link directly in your code. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.9/angular.js

Answer (score 0):

Right-click "save as..". Or take the zipped version.